# AxImp.exe generates less dll files then expected

Tags: com, activex, atl

I've created an MFC activeX control named M.

and created another ATL project named N.

M references N, meaning M uses some classes in N.

M -> N

Then I compile all of then to .ocx files and run AxImp.exe against M.ocx like this:

`AxImp M.ocx /out:AxM.dll`

it only generates AxM.dll and M.dll, while I think it should also generates N.dll

What did I wrong?

thanks.

Comment: No, it only ever generates two interop files.  Only the type library embedded in M.ocx matters, we can't see it.  If N has a type library as well then you need to run Tlbimp.exe on it.  "Uses some classes" is very vague but does not sound like a COM dependency, sounds like a link dependency.  Use Dumpbin.exe /imports on M.ocx to check, if you see N back then you know that M can only be loaded if the OS can find N back.  Which is a tricky problem.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for your answer, there is actually a case `AxImp M.ocx` generates more than 2 dlls, but I can't put the examples files to public due to code policy, so I tried to find out why by creating examples, but still can't get it to work. I could not even reference an interface in a COM project into an ActiveX problem.

https://bitbucket.org/kiinoo/johnnyw3-simple-com
above is my experienmental project.
trying to ref IMathcon interface in ATLProject1 from MFCAc, and finally reference MFCAc into SimpleCSharpConsoleApp project.

Comment: apologize that i'm new to ATL :-(